# PowerShell / PowerShell ISE - How to enter a tab indentation in the command window?

Tags: powershell, command-line, format, powershell-ise

In PowerShell at the command line, how do I enter a tab indentation for multiple line commands?

[image]

Obviously, `[tab]` or `[shift] + [tab]` does not work, otherwise I would not ask this question.

Comment: Have you tried using a SPACE character?

Comment: @lit I suppose that would work, but tab is better right?

Comment: If you only indent by 1, then SPACE is not much different than TAB. If this much script is needed, why not start a new script in the editor window?

Comment: Also, indentation does not count in PowerShell as it does in Python.

Comment: Ehhh, the command line is not an editor

Comment: Agreed; the CLI is not a script-writing interface. Use the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Using PSReadline (built-in to PS 5.1 or available via `Install-Module`) you can make a custom key handler:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord 'ctrl+tab' -ScriptBlock {
    $text = ''
    $cursor = 0
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$text, [ref]$cursor)
    $lastNewLine = [math]::max(0, $text.LastIndexOf("`n", $cursor - 1))
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Replace([math]::min($cursor, $lastNewLine + 1), 0, "    ")
}
```

Then `Ctrl+Tab` will indent the line which the cursor is on, no matter where in the line the cursor is.

Extending this to multiple lines, when you can't really select multiple lines in the console, is left as an exercise for the reader.